# java HttpClient post text/plain

Tags: java, httpclient, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I have a AQL query that looks like this

```
items.find(
    {
        "path":{"$match":"product/*"},
        "size":{"$gt" : "10000"},
        "type":{"$eq" : "file"}

    }
)
```

and my java HttpClient looks like this

```
    String url = "http://restEndpoint/";
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

    request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");

   /*how do I insert the data here*/
    request.setEntity();

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

I'm wondering how do I insert the query in request.setEntity as it only accepts HttpEntity

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're using Apache httpcomponents.

There is a tutorial that explains [how to use entities](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e95).

There are various entity classes that you can use to wrap your content in, e.g. for String content you can use something like this:

```
StringEntity myEntity = new StringEntity("important message", ContentType.create("text/plain", "UTF-8"));
```

Just make sure you use the correct mimetype.

The javadoc about the available entity classes is available [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/AbstractHttpEntity.html).